# Store and Retrieve data across different domains in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to know if following scenario is possible via electron.

In my electron app User login to Example.com and token is saved in localstorage like below

```
localStorage["token"] = "123frkk23" ;
```

Now I need to use that token localStorage["token"]  if user navigate to any of the webpages other than example.com , I use preload.js to run in every page like below

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 700,
    height: 900,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      webSecurity: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });
```

Above preload.js runs on every webpages , I can get the token via localstorage on example.com via  preload.js , Now is it possible in Electron app to use this token in any of the webpages(different domain) I visit.,thanks.